# How to make the dialog appear at the center of the bar using flot?

Tags: javascript, flot, bar-chart

I have a flot bar chart here as a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/50/). Now i need to show a dialog originating from the center of bar1 if a user presses anywhere on bar1. How to do that?

Although we can capture the press event of bar1 through `obj.dataIndex == 0`.. I dont know how to specify the values of x and y so that the dialog appear from the center..

Comment: That was harder than I thought. Here is a demo with more information [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/4NmwK/) - I have run out of time

Comment: hi @mplungjan i have done it... Please check it out and let me know if i can improve it http://jsfiddle.net/coderslay/WnC9B/51/ thanks :)

Comment: What am I looking at? I see one if I click near the bottom and undefined near the top

Comment: Yes Yes.... Exactly that is because of obj.series.label which i have kept undefined... Is my way correct? And any more efficient way? and will my concept work for other resolutions... I want to know from JavaScript point of view...:)

Comment: I do not understand about the undefined. But the rest looks fine

Comment: Actually when u click the orange bar then the obj.series.label will give you 'one' but if you click on the color '#F8C095' then i haven't specified any label name so it shows undefined. What shall we do about the answer of this question?

Comment: @mplungjan How to check if a div is already shown so that i don't have to recreate the div if it is showing?

Comment: Youmean `var tooltip = $('<div class="tooltip">' + contents + '<span class="arrow"></span></div>');` - you could try $(".tooltip").length

Comment: Can you edit it in jsfiddle and post it as answer such that if a user clicks on bar1 irrespective of top and bottom. The div shouldn't be created for it... And hardcode the obj.series.label to 'one'....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

```
  function showTooltip(x, y, contents) {
    if (!contents) return;
    var tooltip = $("#t1");
    if (!tooltip.html()) {
      tooltip=$('<div id="t1" class="tooltip"><span id="t1content"></span><span class="arrow"></span></div>').appendTo("body");
   }
   tooltip.css({
        top : y - 25,
        left : x + 15
   });
   $("#t1content").html(contents);
   tooltip.fadeIn(10);
  }
```